# Function within a Function TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, function

Can I call a scalar function within a table-valued function?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, just as long as the table-valued function returns a table when it's done.

> User-defined functions can be nested;
>   that is, one user-defined function can
>   call another. The nesting level is
>   incremented when the called function
>   starts execution, and decremented when
>   the called function finishes
>   execution. User-defined functions can
>   be nested up to 32 levels. Exceeding
>   the maximum levels of nesting causes
>   the whole calling function chain to
>   fail. Any reference to managed code
>   from a Transact-SQL user-defined
>   function counts as one level against
>   the 32-level nesting limit. Methods
>   invoked from within managed code do
>   not count against this limit.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx

This is very simplistic, but it does work:

```
--DROP FUNCTION RETURN_INT
--GO
CREATE FUNCTION RETURN_INT ()
    RETURNS INT
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 1
END

GO

--DROP FUNCTION RETURN_TABLE
--GO
CREATE FUNCTION RETURN_TABLE ()
    RETURNS @Test TABLE (
    ID INT 
)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO @Test
    SELECT DBO.RETURN_INT()
RETURN 
END
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that would help a lot

Comment: @Dave, just posted it.  If you need anything else, let me know!