# SQL Function within Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-function

I have a function that gets the recipeid.  I am creating another function that shows the average price with recipename.  How do I use the first function within the second function?

This is what I have so far.  As can be seen, I am using a join for RecipeID, but I want it to use the 1st function I have (let's call it function1) that gets the ID instead.  How do I go about this?

```
CREATE FUNCTION AveragePriceforRecipe() RETURNS @PriceTable TABLE (
  [Amount] smallmoney,
  [RecipeName] nvarchar(75)) AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @PriceTable
       SELECT AVG(Amount)
        FROM Prices JOIN
             RecipePrices ON Prices.PriceID = RecipePrices.PriceID JOIN
             Recipes ON RecipePrices.RecipeID = Recipes.RecipeID
END
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205786/function-within-a-function-tsql

Answer (score 1):

are you using ms sql server (t-sql)? if so, please try the code below:

given that function1 is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION function1(@RecipeName)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RecipeID INT

    SELECT @RecipeID = ID
    FROM Recipes
    WHERE RecipeName = @RecipeName

    RETURN @RecipeID
END
```

getting the recipes price table using function1:

```
CREATE FUNCTION AveragePriceforRecipe (@Amount SMALLMONEY, @RecipeName NVARCHAR(75))
RETURNS @PriceTable TABLE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @PriceTable
    SELECT AVG(Amount)
    FROM Prices
        JOIN RecipePrices ON Prices.PriceID = RecipePrices.PriceID
            AND RecipePrices.RecipeID = function1(@RecipeName)
END
```